# How to use a nonce in font awesome scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, font-awesome, content-security-policy, nonce

How to use a nonce in font awesome scripts ?

I already generated a base64 nonce through my server side and I also inserted it in my font awesome script so that I can use the icons provided by it but I got the error mentioned below :- basically stating that font awesome is trying to add some inline css , how to make it insert it in such a way so that it works?

Error:-
**Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' cdn.jsdelivr.net kit.fontawesome.com 'nonce-somenoncevalue'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.**

What I tried ?
I generated a nonce on server side and applied it on font awesome scripts but It didn't work and also researched a lot but didn't find anything relevant

**generating a nonce**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
let nonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
module.exports = nonce;
```

**setting a nonce property to csp header**

```
const nonce = require("../middleware/nonce");
app.use(helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy:{
        useDefaults:true,
        directives:{
            "default-src":"'self'",
            "script-src":["'self'","cdn.jsdelivr.net","kit.fontawesome.com","ka-f.fontawesome.com","js.stripe.com"],
            "style-src":["'self'","cdn.jsdelivr.net","kit.fontawesome.com",`'nonce-${nonce}'`],
            "connect-src":["'self'","ka-f.fontawesome.com"],
            "frame-src":["'self'","js.stripe.com"]
        }
    }
}));
```

**adding the nonce to fontawesome script**

```
<%- include("./layouts/head.ejs") %>

    <body>
        <%-include("./layouts/nav.ejs") %>
            <% if(editProd==true){ %>
                <div class="container w-100">
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show h-100 w-100" role="alert">
                        <strong>Success!</strong> Your product is successfully edited
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <% }%>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around mainBox flex-wrap progress productBox">
                        <% prods.forEach((element)=> { %>
                            <div class="card position-relative">
                                <% if(loggedIn && userId.toString()==element.userId.toString()){%>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="prodId" value="<%= element._id %>">
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center deleteBtn">
                                        <i class="far fa-window-close fa-3x" nonce='<%= nonce %>'></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <% } %>
                                        <div class="card-body productCard">
                                            <div class="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-evenly align-items-center p-0 imgBox">
                                                <img src="/<%= element.imageurl %>" class="card-img-top displayProd" data-Id="<%=element._id %>" alt='<%=element._id %>'>
                                                <h5 class="card-title fs-4 text-capitalize">
                                                    <%=element.title %>
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between w-100 p-0">
                                                <% if(loggedIn && userId.toString()==element.userId.toString()){%>
                                                    <a href="/edit-product/<%= element._id %>?edit=true"
                                                        class="btn btn-primary details d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">Edit</a>
                                                    <% } %>
                                                        <%- include("./layouts/redirectToCart.ejs",{element:element,loggedIn
                                                            : loggedIn}) %>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                            </div>
                            <% }); %>
                    </div>
                    <%- include("./layouts/pagination.ejs",{currentPage: currentPage,totalPages:totalPages,nextPage:nextPage,prevPage:prevPage}) %>
                    <%- include("./layouts/end.ejs") %>
                    <script src="/mvcshop1/public/productDelete.js"></script>
                    <script src="/mvcshop1/public/productDisplay.js"></script>
// font awesome script 
                    <script nonce='<%= nonce %>' src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bedf74ce64.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Also suggest an alternative approach to solve the error if you can

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: maybe [this documentation](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/security) will help you decide how to fix this

Comment: I tried this documentation already but It didn't helped and I added some code in my question , do check if it help in resolving the problem